# Git push over SSH is not activating remote hooks

Tags: linux, ssh, git, hook

I have the following problems that **git push over SSH** **is not activating remote hooks**.

The server where Git repo is Linux ubuntu.
Git version 1.7.9.5 
My path to repo hooks **/path/test.git/hooks/update**; with **Update** executable (chmod +x)

In update file I put just simple check to be sure it works.

**#!/bin/bash** 
**echo "Hello World" 

echo "098" >> test.txt 

exit 1** 
I am connecting from Ubuntu (on Virtualbox) with following steps:

**touch somefile.txt 

git add -A 

git commit -ma "my somefile add"**

Then:

**git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master**

**Counting objects: 3, done. 

Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. 

Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. 

Total 3 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0) 

remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done 

remote: 

remote: New Changes: 

remote:   https://URL/gerrit/15676 

remote: 

To ssh://mylogin@URL:29418/reponame** 
 *** [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master**

As you see my update script is not activated during "push".

What could be check why it happens like this?

Comment: On what machine do you store the hooks?

Comment: hooks are located on server.